# Contenteditable paste as plain text

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would like to restrict the paste text on the `contenteditable` to plain text. I have a html file and ts file.

I tried using this method but it keeps showing this error message:
**Property 'clipboardData' does not exist on type 'Event'**.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector('#divId').addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      console.log(text);
      window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
  })
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="divId" style="border: 1px #ebedf2 solid; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600; font-family: sans-serif; color: #575962;"></div>
```

Comment: you shouldn't cuz ot how will you prevent the default?

Comment: [`clipboardData` is experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) you shouldn't rely on it